# Initialize local variable inside closure

Tags: swift

Is it possible to initialize a variable in a closure? Specifically, the following code gives an error:

```
func doSomething(todo: (Void -> Void)) -> Void {
    todo()
}

var i: Int
doSomething( { i = 3} )
print(i)
```

because `i` is captured before being initialized. Of course, I can always just use default initialization for the variable and skipping that is most of the time a microoptimization, but I'm wondering.

---

Edit:

In the end I've gone with an implicitly unwrapped optional `var i: Int!`, 
thanks to @Laffen and @dfri for pointing me in the right direction. Using an optional should be the best way in the majority of cases.

Comment: The error is about `i` not being initialised - so initialise it! if you declare it as `var i: Int = 0`, your example will print 3.

Comment: Seems to me declaring it with `var i: Int = 0` is equivalent to using default initialization of `0`. My question was _not_ "How do I make this error go away".

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @HBu: it clearly is *not* "equivalent". There is no default initialisation in Swift. What you are doing is declaring the variable's type, not initialising it.

Comment: Usually for cases such as this one---declaring a variable and initializing it at a later stage, say, through a closure---one uses optional variables. It isn't really the same, _per se_, as the optionals will have value `nil` at time of declaration, but at least worth a comment. (`var i: Int?` .... `print(i ?? "nil")`)

Comment: I would have expected that adding @noescape to the todo variable would have resolved the error but it doesn't.

Comment: @Grimxn: `var i: Int = 0` _is_ clearly equivalent to `var i: Int = Int()` aka initialization. Just try it in a playground. I _know_ that the error is about `i` not being initialized. I _know_ how to make my example print 3. And speaking about playground and to split hairs: there _is_ default initialization in Swift says [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) Okay, it's only called default initialization if it's a initializer provided by swift but that doesn't change the point of the question.

Comment: But your original question didn't state var i: Int = Int() - which *does* initialise - you asked about var i: Int , which is simply a declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no default value is set for the initialization, you should append the `?` to  make this an optional.

```
var i: Int?

func someFunc(){
    i = 1
}
```

**Note:** To enhance the readability of this answer together with the comment made by @dfri, I've included the comment in the answer:

> Perhaps worth mentioning that `i` is now an implicitly unwrapped optional, so it's possible for `i` to take a value `nil`, whereafter trying to access `nil`-valued `i` will not prompt compile time warning, however yielding a runtime exception. E.g., `i=nil` ... `print(i)`. For this case, I find it safer to let `i` be a "regular" optional, in which case compiler will prompt you for unwrapping (and you can do this in a safe manner rather than implicitly using forced unwrapping `!` by default: e.g. `var i: Int?` .... `print(i ?? "nil"))`, or, safely print `"nil"` if not unwrapped.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `i` is now an implicitly unwrapped optional, so it's possible for `i` to take a value `nil`, whereafter trying to access `nil`-valued `i` will _not_ prompt compile time warning, however yielding a runtime exception. E.g., `i=nil` ... `print(i)`. For this case, I find it safer to let `i` be a "regular" optional, in which case compiler will prompt you for unwrapping (and you can do this in a safe manner rather than implicitly using forced unwrapping `!` by default: e.g. `var i: Int?` .... `print(i ?? "nil")`),  or, safely print `"nil"` if not unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the print(i) inside the closure then it works.

```
func doSomething(todo: (Void -> Void)) -> Void {
    todo()
    print(i)
}

var i: Int
doSomething( { i = 3} )
```

If the value is not mutated outside the closure Swift will make a copy of that value and so the i referred to outside the doSomething is different from the one inside the doSomething.